# Google Drive Api Deprecated, какова замена?

Tags: android, google-drive

Делаю приложение на android, подключил Drive Api  и на таких моментах : 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и таких :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наблюдаются Deprecated Методы поля и прочее, собственно вопрос к знающим и/или более опытным Android developer-ам, чем и как заменить, или если есть рабочий пример с актуальным Api то пожалуйста дайте ссылочку.